# How to separate string to more cells VBA

Tags: vba, excel, split

I'm trying to separate a string e. g. "M - F" just to "M" and "F". And then put theese new strings into two diferent cells. I tried Split method, but it still reports some errors and I don't know what to do. 
Can anyone help.

```
Function Aprobace(apr As String) As String
    Dim spt() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    If InStr(1, apr, " - ") < 1 Then
        Aprobace = apr
    Else
        spt = Split(apr, " - ")
        For i = 0 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(spt)
        ActiveCell.Value = spt(i).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why not text to columns?

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is: `ActiveCell.Value = spt(i).Value`. Since `spt` is declared as an array at this point and not a worksheet range, it doesn't make sense for it to be using the `.Value` method like a `Range` would.

Secondly, `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(spt)` doesn't make sense to use on `spt` because of similar reasons. Since `spt` is still just in memory again and not actually a range on the worksheet, it shouldn't be utilized in worksheet functions. If you are trying to find out how many indexes that the `spt` is filled with after the `Split` method is run, this is more appropriate: `UBound(spt)`

See the revised function:

```
Function Aprobace(apr As String) As String
    Dim spt() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Long

    If InStr(1, apr, " - ") < 1 Then
        Aprobace = apr
    Else
        spt = Split(apr, " - ")
        count = UBound(spt)  '<----------------------
        For i = 0 To count
            ActiveCell.Value = spt(i) '<-----------------------
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: These solutions address the reasons OPs code would not execute. I worry though about a function that relies on a particular cell being active when it's called (putting the output into `ActiveCell`)... that's a (another) problem waiting to happen.